# "Input type file.files" selector not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get information about the file being uploaded in an HTML input with the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    file_size = $("#my_file").files[0].size;
    alert(file_size);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="my_file" type="file" name="my_name" />
  <input id="btn" type="button" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't work, and the console returns: `$("#my_file").files is undefined`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`$("#my_file")` is a jQuery object, and a jQuery object does not have a property `files`...

To get the DOM element out of jQuery, do

```
$("#my_file")[0].files[0].size
```

---

As an extra note, if you have not selected any file, `($("#my_file"))[0].files[0]` gives you `undefined` and `($("#my_file"))[0].files[0].size` will throw error.
You are recommended to add a check...

```
if ($("#my_file")[0].files.length > 0) {
    file_size = $("#my_file")[0].files[0].size
} else {
    // no file chosen!
}
```

Answer (score 6):

jQuery object doesn't have `files` property, you can use the old `getElementById` or jQuery `get` method for selecting the DOM Element object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    file_size = document.getElementById("my_file").files[0].size;
    alert(file_size);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="my_file" type="file" name="my_name" />
  <input id="btn" type="button" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    file_size = document.getElementById("my_file").files[0].size;
    alert(file_size);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="my_file" type="file" name="my_name" />
  <input id="btn" type="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is an exact copy of another answer posted 4 years ago.